# jQuery imgAreaSelect hide/show?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been trying to hide and show the `imgAreaSelect` selection box depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

I've tried:

```
    var ias = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
    ias.setOptions({ show: false });
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I have had to resort to:

```
    $('div.imgareaselect-selection').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-border1').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-border2').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-border3').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-border4').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-handle').hide();
    $('div.imgareaselect-outer').hide();
```

but it seems a little cumbersome and I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the instance after you change the options - http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#api-methods .  Although in truth, I'm not sure if you should be using { hide: true } or {show: false}.

```
var ias = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
ias.setOptions({ hide: true });
ias.update();
```

Comment: To redisplay, I needed to use ias.setOptions({ show: true }); For some reason, false as a value gave peculiar, half-baked results. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I never used imgAreaSelect myself, but in the [docs](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html) there is no option `show` present, but one named `hide`. Did you try this?

```
var ias = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
ias.setOptions({ hide: true });
ias.update();
```

As BBonifield points out, it seems like you have to call `update()` after changing options.

Alternatively you could use:

```
$('div[class^=imgareaselect-]').hide();
```

This selects all `div`s which have a class that begins with "imageareaselect-" and hides them.

Comment: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#callback-functions section 8, second code snippet ias.setOptions({ show: true });

Comment: your alternative is certainly better than mine! One day I'll buy a jQuery book and read it.

Comment: Yes, just saw it, seems to be the missing `update()` call then..?

Comment: I'm just reading "jQuery in Action (second edition)". I would warmly recommend this lecture. :-)

Comment: $('div[class^=imgareaselect-]').hide(); was the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a cancel selection function in the API, so use it like this:

```
var ias = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
ias.cancelSelection();
```

BOOM!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get an instance back and call the API methods.  You can simply:

```
var ias = $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({ hide: true });
```

You can see all other method calls here (official documentation): http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the options mentioned here. Nothing worked.
I expected some api call to do it. But none of them actually worked.

I ended up doing manually like this:

```
$(".imgareaselect-selection").hide();
$(".imgareaselect-outer").hide();
$(".imgareaselect-border1").hide();
$(".imgareaselect-border2").hide();
```

My page structure is complex. This seems doing the trick.