# 2 selectboxes one for updating the other onclick cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I have a form callled "Project", it contains a selectbox with the names of the companies , the other selectbox is hidden and is called "Staff" and is to be made visible and filled with the names and ids of users that are working for the selected company.

```
>>selectbox "Company" visible   |   >>selectbox "Staff" hidden
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Company microsoft]           |   [null]
[Company aol]                  |                
[Company google]                 |                      
[Company facebook]             |                        

--> onclik selectbox "Company" -> e.g. google

>>selectbox "Staff" visible
------------------------------
[Staff X of google]
[Staff Y of google]
[Staff Z of google]
```

in Html

```
<form id="ProjectAddForm">
<select id="ProjectCompany" multiple="multiple" onClick="makeStaffVisible">
    <option value="1">Microsoft</option>
    <option value="2">AOL</option>
    <option value="3">Google</option>
    <option value="4">facebook</option>
</select>
<select id="Staff" style="visibility: hidden">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I just don't know how to realize that with cakephp. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @akikois you are a member for 5 months by now. So far, you did not accept a single answer to your six questions. Please revisit your questions. If an answer solved your issue please tick the answer as the accepted answer or edit the question to point out why no answer solved your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will be easily done with jQuery plugin: [jquerychained](http://www.codeassembly.com/Simple-chained-combobox-plugin-for-jQuery/)

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly that here: [jQuery imgAreaSelect hide/show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709633/jquery-imgareaselect-hide-show)

I thoroughly recommend jQuery with Cake. It's very easy to implement and has all the javascript you'll ever need.

If you need more details about how to do this task after reading that link, let me know and I'll post some code.